# How to call C# function in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sqlclr

SQL Server 2005 supports CLR so it means we can use CLR in backend so how to do that, I have some function in c# which do some complex manipulation with date-time variable now I want to use those functions in SP. First of all IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO THIS.

Comment: what sort of "some complex manipulation with date-time variable "; I personally haven't come across one that can't be done in TSQL...

Comment: yes u are right that we can do all manipulation with datetime in TSQL. here complex manipulation part is in dll so we have to use them ( re usability ). so My question is can we call those function in TSQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use .NET in a SQL Server 2005 database.  Be aware that the .NET version supported by SQL Server 2005 is 2.0.

[Here's a link for an introduction to Making a CLR stored procedure using Visual Studio](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this TSQL example

```
USE [XXX] GO SET ANSI_NULLS OFF GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF GO CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Testing_XXX]
@broadcastId [int],
@XXXTemplateHtml [nvarchar](max),
@XXXTemplateText [nvarchar](max),
@XXXTemplateSubject [nvarchar](max),
@XXXTemplateEmailHeaders [nvarchar](max),
@XXXTemplateHeader [nvarchar](max),
@XXXTemplateFooter [nvarchar](max),
@masterTemplate [nvarchar](max),
@parseOptions [nvarchar](4000),
@xsltTemplate [nvarchar](max) OUTPUT WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME  SolutionXXX.ProjectXXX].[StoredProcedures].[XXX_Parser_Parse] GO
```

When you call

```
EXTERNAL NAME [SolutionXXX.ProjectXXX].[StoredProcedures].[XXX_Parser_Parse]
```

It invokes a C# function looks like this

```
 [SqlProcedure]
public static void XXX_Parser_Parse(
    SqlInt32 broadcastId,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateHtml,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateText,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateSubject,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateEmailHeaders,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateHeader,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString XXXTemplateFooter,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    SqlString masterTemplate,
    SqlString parseOptions,
    [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] 
    out SqlString xsltTemplate)
{
//blah blah blh
}
```