# Way to access a REST Service via a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, rest

We are looking for a way to call a REST service from a SQL Server 2008 & newer stored procedure. We do not need to get any information from this service. We just need to force the call to run in the middle of a stored procedure.

I have found some 3rd party options or CLR; but I refuse to think there isn't an easier way since we just need to fire a call and don't need anything in return.

Hopefully someone can shed some light. Thanks!

Comment: I would believe using a SQL-CLR assembly is most likely the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

You could make a SQL Agent job to run a PowerShell script, then run the job via `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job`.  That way you wouldn't need any external scripts or utilites, nor any SQL-CLR.

Your job step would be something like:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://stackoverflow.com/')
$result = $request.GetResponse()
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think at least of 2 ways of doing that:

1) Probably prefered way:

Make a C# dll and call its function from the store procedure example:
[How to call C# function in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002382/how-to-call-c-sharp-function-in-stored-procedure)

2) Call the rest service with the help of [CURL utility](http://curl.haxx.se/).

```
DECLARE @PassedVariable VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @PassedVariable = 'SqlAuthority.com'
SET @CMDSQL = 'c:findword.bat' + @PassedVariable
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL

have the call to the ws inside the bat file
```