# Insert trigger that compares values and sends mail

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Currently, I've tested this trigger that sends me an email at every insert in the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dr_insert ON data_record 
    AFTER INSERT 
AS 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'TEST',
        @recipients = 'azfarkashif@hotmail.com',
        @body = 'New data uploaded',
        @subject = 'TriggerTest';

GO
```

How do I customize this trigger such that it considers a column from the newly inserted row, compares it (e.g. temp > 70 || temp <40) and if the condition matches, THEN sends me the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *inserted* table. It is also called a magic table in SQL.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dr_insert ON data_record 
    AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp INT

    SET @temp = (SELECT column FROM inserted)

    IF @temp > 70 || @temp <40
        BEGIN
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'TEST',
            @recipients = 'azfarkashif@hotmail.com',
            @body = 'New data uploaded',
            @subject = 'TriggerTest';
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: Currently, I'm using this.
SET @temp=(SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM data_record WHERE Value_Type = 'DCU Battery' ORDER BY Value_ID DESC) thinking that the top value in descending order would be the one that's just been inserted

Comment: Also, If I want to print the temp variable in the email body, how do i do that?
I'm trying "@body = 'Temperature alert! Temperature is' + @temp" but it's not working

Comment: It is not working and you must be getting data type conversion error as you are appending *int* to *string*. This will work - `@body = 'Temperature alert! Temperature is' + cast(@temp as varchar)`

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Sorry for bugging you continuously, but do you know of any way to call an external API from a stored procedure? If you could hook me up with any link you might have used, that would be helpful!

Comment: Yes that's possible but not directly using T-SQL. You have to rely on SQL CLR. Here are some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124585/way-to-access-a-rest-service-via-a-sql-server-stored-procedure