# How to get call trigger on c# Method using store procedure when i update table data without using sqldependency

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, sqldependency

i want call a C# method when i update table data or delete table data on every way like sql newquery 'Delete top(1) FROM [dbo].[Leaves]' like this and call c# method using store procedure. i perform it on sql dependencey but i don't need this i perform it using store procedure. you can see my code of sqldependecey. but i want another way to call this method using store procedure.

```
public class NotificationEvent
{
    private delegate void RateChangeNotification(DataTable table);
    private SqlDependency dependency;
    string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Message;Integrated Security=True";
    string UserName = Environment.UserName;

    public void RegisterForNotification()
    {
        var connectionString = ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var queryString = "SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[Leaves]";
            using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                // Starting the listener infrastructure...
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

                var oDependency = new SqlDependency(oCommand);
                oDependency.OnChange += OnNotificationChange;

                // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
                oCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }


    private void OnNotificationChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Notification Info: " + e.Info);
        //Re-register the SqlDependency. 
        //var oDependency = new SqlDependency();
        //oDependency.OnChange += OnNotificationChange;
        RegisterForNotification();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Umar Asif If the problem you face is totally regarding DB-to-DB communication, I would recommend a concept called "Merge Replication" in SQL Server (using Publisher-Subscriber(s)) design between DBs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Otherwise, if your problem requires a solution ONLY through a call to C# method, please refer:

[How to call C# function in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002382/how-to-call-c-sharp-function-in-stored-procedure)